# Solution of $ax+xb=c$ in a division ring

Tags: ring-theory, quaternions

The equation  $ax+xb=c$ in the quaternions skew field ($a,b,c,x \in \mathbb{H}$) has solution:
$$
 x=  \left(|b|^2+2b_0a +a^2\right)^{-1}   \left( ac +c \bar b\right) 
$$
Where $|b|,b_0,\bar b$ are respectively the module, the real part and the conjugate of $b$.
Searching a  similar formula for a  generic division ring $\mathbb{A}$ I find that, if there exists $\bar b \in \mathbb{A}$ and $h,k \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{A})$, where $ \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{A})$ is the center of $\mathbb{A}$, such that:
$$
\begin{cases}
b \bar b=h\\
b+\bar b=k
\end{cases}
$$
 we have the solution:
$$
x=\left(a^2+ka+h \right)^{-1} \left( ac +c \bar b\right) 
$$
Is that the only possible formal solution of the given equation?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the solution for $ax + xb = c$! I've been looking for it all over the Internet. What book did you get it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ring of differential operators in x.  By this I mean differential operators of the form
$$
\sum_{i=0}^N p_i(x) {d^n \over dx^n},
$$
where $p_i$ is a polynomial in $x$.
Multiplication is given by composition of operators. As a ring, this is generated by $x$ and $y=d/dx$.  This is not a division ring, but can be embedded in one.

$x$ and $y$ satisfy an equation,
$$
yx - xy = 1.
$$
This is an equation of your form, where $a = x$, $b = -x$, and $c=1$, but is not an example of family of solutions you mention.

Comment: I'm tempting to prove that "is not an example of family of solutions" I mention, but I have some trouble. I'm not an expert of differential operators (I'm not an expert at all). Can you give a proof? Or some other information as what is the  function space on which act the operators and what is the center of the operators algebra ?

Comment: The center is scalar multiples of 1, so $\bar{b}$ has to be $c/x$, for some scalar $c$.  But $x + c/x$ isn't a scalar multiple of 1.

Comment: If you're curious to learn more about the ring, the search term to use is "Weyl algebra".  (The Wikipedia page is unilluminating, however.)

Comment: thanks for the hint! Now I would like to know if there is a rule to see if an equation like that has a solution or not. But I will put a new question.