# How to integrate $e^{t \ln q} p e^{-t \ln q} dt$ for quaternion $q$ and $p$?

Tags: integration, quaternions

Trying to solve an inertial navigation problem in terms of quaternions,
I ended up with the following indefinite integral
$$
I = \int e^{t \ln q} \, p \, e^{-t \ln q} dt,
$$
where
$q \in \mathbb H$ is a unit quaternion,
$p \in \mathbb H$ is a pure imaginary quaternion,
and both $q$ and $p$ are constant with respect to
the integration variable $t \in \mathbb R$.

Assuming $q \neq 1$, I integrated by parts:
$$
I = \int
    \underbrace{\mathstrut{}e^{t \ln q} p}_u \,
    \underbrace{\mathstrut{}e^{-t \ln q}}_{v'} \, dt =
e^{t \ln q} p e^{-t \ln q} (-\ln q)^{-1} -
\int e^{t \ln q} (\ln q) \, p e^{-t\ln q} (-\ln q)^{-1} \, dt, \\
I = e^{t \ln q} p \, e^{-t \ln q} (-\ln q)^{-1} + (\ln q) \, I \,  (\ln q)^{-1},
$$
and got the equation
$$
(\ln q) \, I - I \, (\ln q) = e^{t \ln q} \, p \, e^{-t \ln q}.
$$

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069759/solution-of-axxb-c-in-a-division-ring) I learned that
the general solution for the $ax + xb = c$ equation is
$$
x= \left( |b|^2 + 2b_0a + a^2 \right)^{-1} \left( ac +c b^* \right),
$$
but it did not work for my case because of zero quaternion inversion.
I also tried to expand this equation into quaternion components,
but came to a system of linear equations with a singular matrix.
This looks quite strange to me, since I'm pretty sure this integral should exist.

Could please someone point me to a mistake in my computations
and show how to calculate this antiderivative properly?
Might there be a well known solution for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that conjugation preserves vectors, so the integrand and hence $\mathbf{I}$ are pure imaginary.

For pure quaternions $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$,

$$ \mathbf{ab}=-\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}. $$

Thus, writing $``\ln q "=\mathbf{v}$ we have

$$ (\ln q)\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{I}(\ln q)=2\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{I}=\exp(t\mathbf{v})\mathbf{p}\exp(-t\mathbf{v}). $$

Note that $\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{I}$ deletes the $\mathbf{v}$-component of $\mathbf{I}$, so this equation fails to "see" this component. However, this actually isn't a problem: conjugating by $\exp(t\mathbf{v})$ fixes the $\mathbf{v}$-component of $\mathbf{p}$, call it $\mathbf{p}_{\|}$, within the integrand for $\mathbf{I}$, so we may conclude the $\mathbf{v}$-component for $\mathbf{I}$ must be $\mathbf{I}_{\|}=t\mathbf{p}_{\|}$.

Applying $\mathbf{v}\times$ to $2\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{I}_{\perp}=\exp(t\mathbf{v})\mathbf{p}\exp(-t\mathbf{v})$ (with $v=\|\mathbf{v}\|$) yields

$$ -2v^2\mathbf{I}_{\perp}=\mathbf{v}\times\big(e^{t\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{p}e^{-t\mathbf{v}}\big)  $$

from which we may conclude

$$ \mathbf{I}=t\big(\mathbf{p}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|}\big)\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|}+\frac{1}{2}\big(e^{t\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{p}e^{-t\mathbf{v}}\big)\times\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\,\,\|\mathbf{v}\|^2}+\mathbf{C}. $$

---

Another route is to expand the exponentials $\exp(t\mathbf{v})$ using Euler's formula so you can multiply out and integrate directly. This works especially nice if, setting $\hat{\mathbf{v}}=\frac{\mathbf{v}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|}$ you write $\mathbf{p}$ with respect to an oriented orthonormal basis $\{\mathbf{u},\hat{\mathbf{v}},\mathbf{w}\}$.